# How to fix 'org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader' does not implement interface 'org.apache.http.NameValuePair'

Tags: android, android-volley, proguard, release

I use volley for android requests. but when I release app and request for first time with volley, this error occur and app crash.
But, when i disable proguard it's OK.

The log from the app is:

```
    java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class 'org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader' does not implement interface 'org.apache.http.NameValuePair' in call to 'java.lang.String org.apache.http.NameValuePair.getName()' (declaration of 'com.android.volley.a.a' appears in base.apk)
        at com.android.volley.a.a.a(BasicNetwork.java:65)
        at com.android.volley.a.a.a(BasicNetwork.java:8)
        at com.android.volley.h.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:8)
```

I am building for API 28, running on API 28 and using uses-library as suggested:

```
        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
```

Comment: could u log/show what error you tought?

Comment: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class 'org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader' does not implement interface 'org.apache.http.NameValuePair' in call to 'java.lang.String org.apache.http.NameValuePair.getName()' (declaration of 'com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork' appears in /data/app/ir.snayab.snaagrin-581o2YfpqDhdf8MGF9IysQ==/base.apk!classes2.dex)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.convertHeaders(:278)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(:101)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(:114)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class 'org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader' does not implement interface 'org.apache.http.NameValuePair'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56665050/java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror-class-org-apache-http-message-basichead)

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?