# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class 'org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader' does not implement interface 'org.apache.http.NameValuePair'

Tags: android, apk, release

I have an issue in `Released APK`. `java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError` Error comes when install and open release APK. But my debug APK is working properly. I saw lot of links and stackoverflow question but I didn't got any solution. What should I do?

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class 'org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader' does not implement interface 'org.apache.http.NameValuePair' in call to 'java.lang.String org.apache.http.NameValuePair.getName()' (declaration of 'com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork' appears in /data/app/com.mypackage.myprojectname-XI7DFLjbpTwZkGhQ3WYiBQ==/base.apk)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.convertHeaders(SourceFile:3)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(SourceFile:8)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(SourceFile:8)
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you enable `proguard` ?

Comment: Yes I have enabled proguord

Comment: -dontnote org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn org.apache.**  add in proguard file

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868072/android-volley-always-fails-with-proguard) post for your proguard settings

Comment: @Pavya Same Error

Comment: @ShivamKumar https://stackoverflow.com/q/54414287/2299040 may help you

Comment: @SahilManchanda Thanks for you reply but i have already follow given link but didn't get solution

Comment: @ShivamKumar ok, can you create a sample project which reproduces the same error so that we can give it a try?!

Comment: @SahilManchanda If i remove proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro' on buildType release then app not chashed

Comment: You are basically turning off the proguard with the above lines. can you share your proguard file content

Comment: Also try to look into https://github.com/google/volley/blob/master/consumer-proguard-rules.pro and see if it helps

Comment: also add -keepattributes *Annotation*

Comment: @Pavya added all the keep attributes still same issue  -keep class org.apache.http.HttpResponse { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added volley library & resolved my issue.

```
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
```